# React Native: Array of components

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I am trying to print an array of JSX elements:

```
return (
        <View
        style={[
          commonStyles.sectionContainer,
          commonStyles.spaceBottom1x,
          { width: "100%" },
        ]}
      >
        { ['a', 'b'].forEach((letter) => { 

            <View>
                <Text>Hola</Text>
            </View>
        })}
        </View>
)
```

But it does not print... what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to instead.

And use the parameter with a wrap {letter} to render.

Like this:

```js
<View style={styles.app}>
  { ['a', 'b'].map((letter) => 
    <Text>{letter}</Text>
  )}
</View>
```